# React keep state of previous component and render new state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on a news app where I call an API and display cards of trending news.(picture 1)

```
  <div style={{display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap', padding: 20, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      {this.state.news.map(news => (
        <NewsCard
          key={news.url}
          _id={news.url}
          description={news.description}
          image={news.urlToImage}
          source={news.source.name}
          title={news.title}
          summary={this.state.summary}
          onExpand={this.handleDetailClick.bind(this, news.url)}
          onSave={this.handleDetailClick.bind(this, news.url)}
        />
    ))}
    </div>
```

Upon expanding a card it the shows a gist of the article after calling a second API.(picture 2)

```
  handleDetailClick = link => {
// console.log('hadle detail', link);
API.summarize(link)
  .then((res) => {
    // console.log(res.body);
    this.setState({
      summary: res.body
    })
    // console.log(this.state.summary);
  })
```

}

However I am stuck on this issue whereupon calling the gist API on a second card the first card gets the gist of the second card. How do I prevent this from happening?(picture 3)

So far I've tried using the componentDidUpdate lifecycle method to compare states and keep the state persistent for the first card but I am not able to figure this out.

Any pointers?

[image: b0][image: b1][image: b2]

Comment: can you include the relevant code for this?

Comment: added some code

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add in some way of associating the `summary` data with the correct news item. Currently your program just gives the current `summary` to all `NewsCard` components.

The simplest way to do this with your current code would be to also record the url that the summary came from in your main component's (the parent of the `NewsCard` components) state as well. Then only pass the summary to the correct news item.

For example (adding `summaryUrl` to `state`) (note the `summary=` line):

```js
<div style={{display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap', padding: 20, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
  {this.state.news.map(news => (
    <NewsCard
      key={news.url}
      _id={news.url}
      description={news.description}
      image={news.urlToImage}
      source={news.source.name}
      title={news.title}
      summary={news.url === this.state.summaryUrl ? this.state.summary : ""}
      onExpand={this.handleDetailClick.bind(this, news.url)}
      onSave={this.handleDetailClick.bind(this, news.url)}
    />
))}
</div>
```

So we only pass `this.state.summary` to the `NewsCard` if the url for the current news item matches the url for the summary.

Then the `handleDetailClick` method should be updated to:

```js
handleDetailClick = link => {
  // console.log('hadle detail', link);
  API.summarize(link)
  .then((res) => {
      // console.log(res.body);
    this.setState({
     summary: res.body,
     summaryUrl: link,
    })
    // console.log(this.state.summary);
  })

}
```

Another way you might consider doing this is by passing the second API call off to the `NewsCard` component. So each `NewsCard` would have its summary as part of its own state and would fetch the summary when clicked on. This way there would be no confusion about which news item the summary belongs to. It could also help clean up your parent component by delegating tasks/data to children as the component grows.

Comment: @Yash did this help? Is there anything missing?